# Inject extends services in Fragment in Android

Tags: android

I'd like to create a fragment using a generic Service, but can't find a way to define the service.

It could be represented like that.

```
Fragment MyGenericFragment<S service> extends Fragments
    private S service;

Fragment FragmentA extends MyGenericFragment<SpecializedService>
```

In my FragmentA I try define my specialized service like this :

```
@Inject
SpecializedService service;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).inject(this);
}
```

Is there a way to construct Fragments this way.
Objective is to avoid duplicate code for a same representation.

Comment: By `Service`, do you mean `android.app.Service`? If so, neither an activity nor a fragment has a reference to that `Service`, nor should they.

Comment: no, my service, using for doing jobs.

Comment: I use them in my app, injecting them with Dagger when I need it.

Answer (score 0):

I find a first solution, but I don't know if it's a good practice (quite sure not, but do the job).

FragmentA can declare a service, receiving it by Dagger inject and set it as the service

```
Fragment FragmentA extends MyGenericFragment<SpecializedService>

@Inject
DedicatedService dedicatedService;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    ((App) getActivity().getApplication()).inject(this);
    this.service = dedicatedService;
}
```